# MapBox GL JS rotate the camera around a point with one finger touch

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

How can I solve that rotate the camera around a point with **one finger touch**?
The `dragRotate` do the same thing, but it isn't working with one finger. This kind of camera control is in the Pokemon Go too.

Comment: Are you able to explain what you're trying to do a bit more clearly? What is "one finger touch"?

Comment: I want to do the same thing what dragRotate do but with a swipe touch and not with multitouch. https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html At this demo on mobile you can move the camera with a swipe touch.

Comment: Ah, I can't think of any easy way to implement that with Mapbox-GL-JS. You'd have to use a mousehandler.